# CGI returns OK for 403

Tags: perl

I wrote a simple script to serve custom HTTP error 403 page and I use the following code:

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;

print header(
  '-Status'        => 403,
  '-Type'          => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  '-Cache-Control' => 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0',
  '-Pragma'        => 'no-cache');

...

print $html;
```

I expected system to return `Forbidden` status text automatically in HTTP header.

Unfortunately it returns `403 OK` instead of `403 Forbidden`. Text phrase is more likely added by browser.

Sure, I can explicitly add the status text using `'-Status' => '403 Forbidden'`, but I would still like to know why isn't this done automatically, and why I am getting `OK` status instead...

Is there a way to force `Perl` to add default (English) status text for selected response code?

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate this using Apache 2 and Firefox. Running your snippet on the command line shows that the OK is not added by Perl, so I would guess either your web server or your browser is doing it. According to the [CGI docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#CREATING-A-STANDARD-HTTP-HEADER:), "RFC 2616 expects the human-readable phase to be there as well as the numeric status code," so you really should include it.

Comment: My system is **CentOS release 6.5; Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)** and I am using browser **Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m**

Comment: Okay, I can duplicate using Chrome. The OK is added for other response codes as well (I just tried with 400). I assume the developer tools are at fault.

Comment: @Ωmega I see the same behavior you're stating here running Chromium, Chrome, Firefox. Server is `nginx` on a non-standard linux distro. Are you against adding the `Forbidden` string? Or are you just curious as to why?

Comment: @chrsblck - I am not against, I am just interested in findings why there is such non-logic behavior. It seems to be a browser related issue, as output from `wget` shows no status text. So I believe `Perl` does not add any default status text and send it just as `HTTP/1.1 403`...

Comment: Correct. It is Chrome that rewrites `Status: 403` as `Status: 403 OK`

Comment: From the [HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1): "The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-Phrase." In addition, the "standard" reason phrases are merely recommendations, and "MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol." Like comments on SO, the reason phrases are second-class citizens, and browsers can have their way with them.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is the culprit here. You can verify by running your snippet on the command line, which outputs the following headers:

```
Status: 403
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Notice the status is plain-old `403`.

CGI.pm does not know about the [reason phrases recommended by the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1). Nor should it: they are merely recommendations (not defaults), and you can change them to whatever you want without affecting the protocol (`403 Go away` anyone?). According to the standard, clients are not required to even look at the reason phrase.

So no, unless you modify CGI.pm, there is no way to force Perl to add a reason phrase. Even if you do provide a reason phrase, browsers can do what they wish with them (although most browsers will probably behave sanely).

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking long time for this, and basically it's very simple:

see 
https://serverfault.com/questions/121735/how-to-return-404-from-apache2-cgi-program

In sort:
change

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
print header(
'-Status'        => 403,
'-Type'          => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  ...
```

to

```
print "Status: 403 Forbidden\r\n";
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<h1>403 Forbidden!</h1>";
```

Comment: would like to known why this answer is down voted as it's the only answer that actually sends and http header of 403 forbidden to the client, you can still use `use CGI qw/:standard/;` and print header on a condition that would need to return HTTP 200 OK

Comment: Understood, this is an answer to another question, sorry for that